# VSCode editor full of white space

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

Is someone meeting this issue, I just update the vs code to 1.77.0, then the editor crashed, full of white space.

I tried running vs code with "code --disable-extensions", seems nothing helps.

My os is windows10 21h2 hyper-v

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Better file a bug report in the VS Code repository.

Comment: This caused by the vscode default theme, I switched to Dark+ V2(Experimental), the issue solved :(

Answer (score 0):

I once encounter this type of bug, What I did is I re-install my VSCode, It fixes my problem.